# After updating state, using set, the state still has empty array

Tags: reactjs

just after updating state using setState, if i log state , i am getting empty array even though state is not empty.

I have hook like shown in code below.

```
     const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);

     async function requestPets() {
        const { animals: animalsProperty } = await pet.animals({
          location,
          breed,
          type: animal
        });

        console.log(animalsProperty);

        setPets(animalsProperty || []);
        console.log(pets);
      }
```

Inside `requestPets` function after setting `setPets` with `animalsProperty`, even if `animalsProperty` is not null, when i log pets i am seeing empty array in console. 
may i know why pets is showing empty array instead of value like animalsProperty when i logged pets?

Comment: can u try setPets(animalsProperty) like this without empty array as well as can u show what you are getting in animals property

Comment: i don't think empty array has any problem, it is just an or check to assign empty array when aniamlsProperty is null.
in animasl property i am getting an array like this :(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 1):

`setPets` does async update, so if you `console.log` the state value right after setting it, the previous value will still be shown because it will be updated on subsequent component's render.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use  callback   see if it works as your function is async

```
  setwww(b=>
            {
                return b||[];
            });
```

Comment: setPets is an async function. maybe this is reason behind the behaviour.
is it possible to edit setPets function as it is linked with React library hook useState.
is it possible to use await on setPets ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `pets` will be updated in the render function as expected.
After you fire `setPets`, it won't update the value of `pets` immediately. In other words, you will get the same value of `pets` within that render. The following shown the sequence:

===Initial Render: ===
1. `Pets` is []
2. setPets(`somePets`) => trigger re-render
3. `Pets` is []

===Re-render: ===
4. `Pets` is `somePets`

Comment: exactly same thing is happening. 
but i have a question here.. i am using pets variable as an argument in same file like following,
<Results namedInputProperty={pets} />;
Results file is passed with current pets value as input which is used insdie Results file.
inside Results.js:
const Results = props => {
    console.log(props);
    const namedInputProperty = props.namedInputProperty;
    console.log(namedInputProperty);
    result();}

Comment: nvevr mind i got it. when triggered re-render, Results file gets the updated pets, and setPets is not called again during this time hence old value. thanks.

Comment: i added and useEffect  which will be sheduled after re-render and it logs pets state currect,
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(pets);
  }, [pets]);

i also belive console.log is async function which will be called after re-render just like useAffect. am i right ?
thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean.  
1. You can use console.log(pets) inside render directly, which will give you the current value of pets. 
2. If you only want to log pets when it is updated, use uesEffect(your method) is right.